# jupyter notebook keeps connecting to kernel then changes to unknown

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kernel

the notebook suddenly keeps connecting to kernel then changes to unkown.
i tried to uninstall then install it bbut with no use.
i haven't updated any libs recently so, what can I do?

here is wht the terminal keeps trying to do

```
[I 2023-09-01 22:29:42.640 ServerApp] Skipped non-installed server(s): bash-language-server, dockerfile-language-server-nodejs, javascript-typescript-langserver, jedi-language-server, julia-language-server, pyright, python-language-server, python-lsp-server, r-languageserver, sql-language-server, texlab, typescript-language-server, unified-language-server, vscode-css-languageserver-bin, vscode-html-languageserver-bin, vscode-json-languageserver-bin, yaml-language-server
[I 2023-09-01 22:30:08.820 ServerApp] Kernel started: 53b6ba40-7bc8-4f64-b0e3-8c28b6e1dc0f
[W 2023-09-01 22:31:08.859 ServerApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 53b6ba40-7bc8-4f64-b0e3-8c28b6e1dc0f
[I 2023-09-01 22:31:08.860 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel 53b6ba40-7bc8-4f64-b0e3-8c28b6e1dc0f.
[W 2023-09-01 22:31:13.464 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 10 on kernel 53b6ba40-7bc8-4f64-b0e3-8c28b6e1dc0f
[W 2023-09-01 22:31:18.568 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 20 on kernel 53b6ba40-7bc8-4f64-b0e3-8c28b6e1dc0f
[W 2023-09-01 22:31:23.638 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 30 on kernel 53b6ba40-7bc8-4f64-b0e3-8c28b6e1dc0f
[W 2023-09-01 22:31:28.752 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 40 on kernel 53b6ba40-7bc8-4f64-b0e3-8c28b6e1dc0f
[W 2023-09-01 22:31:34.253 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 50 on kernel 53b6ba40-7bc8-4f64-b0e3-8c28b6e1dc0f
[W 2023-09-01 22:31:39.552 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 60 on kernel 53b6ba40-7bc8-4f64-b0e3-8c28b6e1dc0f
[W 2023-09-01 22:31:44.667 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 70 on kernel 53b6ba40-7bc8-4f64-b0e3-8c28b6e1dc0f
[W 2023-09-01 22:31:49.765 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 80 on kernel 53b6ba40-7bc8-4f64-b0e3-8c28b6e1dc0f
[W 2023-09-01 22:31:54.864 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 90 on kernel 53b6ba40-7bc8-4f64-b0e3-8c28b6e1dc0f
[W 2023-09-01 22:31:59.963 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 100 on kernel 53b6ba40-7bc8-4f64-b0e3-8c28b6e1dc0f
[W 2023-09-01 22:32:05.078 ServerApp] Nudge: attempt 110 on kernel 53b6ba40-7bc8-4f64-b0e3-8c28b6e1dc0f
[E 2023-09-01 22:32:08.878 ServerApp] Uncaught exception GET /api/kernels/53b6ba40-7bc8-4f64-b0e3-8c28b6e1dc0f/channels?session_id=11366ef0-5942-4e0a-8f31-bd0131ed6e06 (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/api/kernels/53b6ba40-7bc8-4f64-b0e3-8c28b6e1dc0f/channels?session_id=11366ef0-5942-4e0a-8f31-bd0131ed6e06', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\youss\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 939, in _accept_connection
        await open_result
      File "c:\users\youss\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\kernels\websocket.py", line 74, in open
        await self.connection.connect()
    asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError: Timeout
[W 2023-09-01 22:32:09.190 ServerApp] Replacing stale connection: 53b6ba40-7bc8-4f64-b0e3-8c28b6e1dc0f:11366ef0-5942-4e0a-8f31-bd0131ed6e06
```